# Why instance in django dosen't work with me?

Tags: python, django

I tried with This function for return with it the fields but it dose not return anything :)

How I can fix that?

**code**

```
def edtiNote(request , slug):
  if slug:
    n = get_object_or_404(addNote , slugUrl=slug)
  if request.method == 'POST':
     form = addNoteForm(request.POST or None , instance=n)
     if form.is_valid():
       new_edit_form = form.save(commit=False)
       new_edit_form.user = request.user
       new_edit_form.save()
       return redirect('../../../notes/'+str(new_edit_form.slugUrl))

 elif request.method == 'GET':
     return redirect('../../../notes/'+str(form.slugUrl))

 else:
    form = addNoteForm()

 context = {'formViews':form}

 return render(request , 'edit_Note.html' , context)
```

Comment: Can you plz share the error you are facing? Also line 3 is not indented to support if block.

Comment: please indent your code exactly like you indented it in your environment so we can be sure we're not looking at indentation issues. The flow here doesn't make sense. And tell us what case is not returning anything. Or what error you're seeing.

Comment: Also, I suggest you take the time to read PEP 8 - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ also did you call the proper function? I believe the name of your function should be editNote not edtiNote and per PEP 8 it should be written edit_note